# Obtaining split extensions with GAP

Tags: representation-theory, gap

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional $K$-algebra (K a field) and $I$ a two-sided ideal of $A$.
(if it helps we can assume that $A$ is a connected quiver algebra or a group algebra and $I$ a power of the Jacobson radical first).
Then the split extension of $A$ by $I$ is the algebra $B=A \oplus I$ with multiplication
$(a_1,i_i)(a_2,i_2)=(a_1 a_2, a_1 i_2+i_1 a_2+i_1 i_2)$.

> Question: Is there an easy way to obtain the split extension $B$ as a $K$-algebra in GAP when given an algebra $A$ and ideal $I$?

Comment: I'm not aware of any dedicated functionality of this for algebras. My suggestion is to try to compose a matrix representation from a faithful representation of $A$ and the action on $I$.